# Can not make asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps

I have two problems:

The first problem I can not do asynchronous function:

```
let address = req.body.merchant_address;
let location = getGeolocation(address);
console.log(location);

async function getGeolocation(address) {
    try {
        const res = await googleMapsClient.geocode({ address: address }).asPromise();
        const location = res.json.results[0].geometry.location;
        console.log(location)
        return location;
    } catch (e) {
        return res.status(422).json({
            err: err
        });
    }
}
```

First it prints `Promise { <pending> }` and then only my coordinates, what did I do wrong in the code above?

```
import maps from '@google/maps';

const googleMapsClient = maps.createClient({
    key: 'my key'
});
```

The second problem. When I build a project, after launching an error `Error: Can not find the module '@ google / maps`. I compile the project using `babel src --out-dir backend` in the `package.json file`. Why doesn't he see `"@ google/maps"`?

Comment: `res.json.results[0].geometry.location` is not a function or a call of any kind, you can't `await` it. It's just some data in an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the fist problem: The first `undefined` is printed by the last line in your code snippet, because it is executed before the callback of `geocode` is resolved (asynchronously).

There is the `asPromise()` function you can use to get rid of callbacks and make your code synchronous with `async/await` like you already started:

```
try {
    const res = await googleMapsClient.geocode({
        address: '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA'
    }).asPromise();

    const location = res.json.results[0].geometry.location;

    // your next stuff with location here...

} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
```

Of course, the whole snippet must be called from within an `async` function.

Comment: Changed the question, did I do everything right? But not working

Comment: @MegaRoks change to `let location = await getGeolocation(address);`. As marked `async` returns the `getGeolocation` a Promise, this must be resolved by calling it with `await`.

Comment: @MegaRoks Anyway, it is not a good practice to change your question entirely. It can happen, the comments and answers make no sense anymore. Please always put the new code under the original question, marked as **EDIT** with some explanation of the change.

Comment: I did what you said but now gives an error `await is a reserved word`

Comment: @MegaRoks as I mentioned already, you have to call the async function with await only from within another async function. It means the whole code must be close in an async function: `(async function() { /* your code here*/} )();`

Comment: Thanks, I missed it